# spring mvc + css+ tiles

Tags: css, spring, tiles

i'm using spring mvc + tiles.
In my web.xml i have

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

In my dispatcher-servelet i have

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

In my jsp

```
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/template/style.css"/>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

but the css is not loaded !!!!
where is the error?

Comment: I think your missing the rest of the "In my JSP" portion here

Comment: Can you show how you are including the style sheet in the `jsp` completely?

Comment: Also show us the generated HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

Change to

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```